# Prove a limit exists and find it if $x_{n+1} = 1- {1\over 4x_n}$, where $x_1 = a$ and range of $a$ is given.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

> Given a recurrence relation:
>   $$
> x_{n+1} = 1- {1\over 4x_n} \\
> x_1 = a \in\Bbb R \\
> n\in\Bbb N
> $$
>   Prove that the limit exists and evaluate:
>   $$
> \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n
> $$
>   given $a$:
>   $$
> \begin{align*}
> a &> {1\over 2} \tag 1\\
> a &\in \left(0, {1\over 4}\right) \tag 2\\
> a & < 0 \tag3
> \end{align*}
> $$

---

First find possible values of the limit by finding fixed points of the recurrence. Suppose $\lim x_n = L$, then:
$$
L = 1 - {1\over 4L} \iff L = {1\over 2}
$$

---

Start with case $(1)$.

**Boundedness.** Using induction one may show that the sequence is bounded below, after that what is left to prove is monotonicity of $x_n$:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 > {1\over 2} &\iff 4x_1 > 2 \\
&\iff {1\over 4x_1} < {1\over 2} \\
&\iff -{1\over 4x_1} > -{1\over 2} \\
&\iff \underbrace{1-{1\over 4x_1}}_{x_2} > {1\over 2}
\end{align}
$$
Suppose $x_n > {1\over 2}$, then:
$$
x_n > {1\over 2} \implies \underbrace{1 - {1\over 4x_n}}_{x_{n+1}} > {1\over 2}
$$
**Monotonicity.** Consider the following expression:
$$
x_{n+1} - x_n = 1 - {1\over 4x_n} - x_n \\
x_{n+1} - x_n = \frac{4x_n - 1 - x_n^2}{4x_n} = \frac{\overbrace{-(x_n - 1)^2}^{<0}}{\underbrace{2x_n}_{>0}} \\
\implies x_{n+1} < x_n
$$
Now by monotone convergence theorem:
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = {1\over 2}}
$$

---

Proceed to case $(2)$. Here we have:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 \in \left(0, {1\over 4}\right)
&\implies {1\over x_1} \in (4, +\infty) \\
&\implies {1\over 4x_1} \in (1, +\infty) \\
&\implies -{1\over 4x_1} \in (-\infty, -1)\\
&\implies \underbrace{1-{1\over 4x_1}}_{x_2} \in (-\infty, 0)
\end{align}
$$

By this we have that $x_2$ is less than $0$. Try one more:
$$
\begin{align}
x_2 \in(-\infty, 0) 
&\implies {1\over x_2} \in (-\infty, 0) \\
&\implies -{1\over 4x_2} \in (0, +\infty) \\
&\implies \underbrace{1-{1\over 4x_2}}_{x_3} \in (1, +\infty) \\
\end{align}
$$

Here we got $x_3 > 1 > {1 \over 2}$. That means we could reindex the sequence from case $(1)$ and set $x_3$ as $x_1$ in $(1)$. Which by monotone convergence theorem once again yields:
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = {1\over 2}}
$$

---

There is actually a third case which was not originally in the post. Here is the reasoning related to it:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 \in (-\infty, 0) &\implies {1\over 4x_1} \in (-\infty, 0) \\
&\implies -{1\over 4x_1} \in (0, +\infty) \\
&\implies 1-{1\over 4x_1} \in (1, +\infty)
\end{align}
$$

As in case $(2)$ lets consider one more term:
$$
\begin{align}
x_2 \in (1, +\infty) &\implies {1\over x_2} \in (0, 1)\\
&\implies {1\over 4x_2} \in \left(0, {1\over 4}\right) \\
&\implies -{1\over 4x_2} \in \left(-{1\over 4}, 0\right) \\
&\implies \underbrace{1-{1\over 4x_2}}_{x_3} \in \left({3\over 4}, 1\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

Here we may either proceed with induction or, since $x_3 > {1\over 2}$, use this result in $(1)$. From which it follows that the limit:
$$
\boxed{\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = {1\over 2}}
$$

---

Thanks to @Did I know a cobweb plot gives a lot of useful information. So [here is a sandbox I've been using](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uyflmrnaiw).

I would like to kindly request a verification of the solution above, any notes or nitpicks are appreciated. Thank you!